# How do I initialize my container when using the Common Service Factory

Tags: wcf, inversion-of-control, ioc-container

The [Common Service Factory](http://commonservicefactory.codeplex.com/) website specifies the following steps for its usage:

- Download the latest release of the Common Service Factory library
- Download the latest release of the Common Service Locator library and
  the adapter for the IoC container that you are using
- Add a reference to the CommonServiceFactory.dll,   Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.dll and the assembly that contains the adapter for your IoC container
- Edit the .svc file for    your service so that Service attribute
  contains the    Assembly-Qualified Name of the service type
- In the .svc file, add the Factory attribute and provide the
  Assembly-Qualified Name of on    of  the factories that are available
  (ServiceHostFactory for SOAP services and WebServiceHostFactory for
  RESTful services) in the Common Service Factory library
- Configure your IoC and setup the Common Service Adapter
- Enjoy using loosely coupled dependencies in your WCF services using
  the IoC container you prefer

I just don't know where should I do the second to last step: Configure your IOC and setup the Common Service Adapter.

Does anyone has an example of how to use the Common Service Factory?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Uhhm... don't you use a Dependency Injection framework? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: The CommonServiceFactory allows you to use your IoC container to create instances of WCF service classes. I would like to know where i the hook to where I can put my IOC initialization code for this to work

Answer (score 2):

You typically setup your container in the startup path of your application. For a ASP.NET application for instance, this would typically be the `Application_Start` event. After you created the container, you wrap the container into a Common Service Locator adapter for the given container and supply it to the `ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider` of the CSL project and you're done.

This is how it looks like when using Simple Injector:

```
var adapter = 
    new SimpleInjectorServiceLocatorAdapter(container);

ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => adapter);
```